# Issue with md-autocomplete?

Tags: angularjs, md-autocomplete

I am using [this](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.4/api/directive/mdAutocomplete) for autocomplete.

If user wants to search his/her name and he/she types the name, after three characters the respective names will come (the search bar available in top bar on dashboard).

After scrolling the dashboard user wants to search for the user, related user names are displaying.

But we are getting response from server.

This is happening when I scroll the dashboard (at the top its working fine).

```
<form id="search" class="navbar-form navbar-right app-search" role="search" ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <md-autocomplete class = "searchShape"
                     ng-disabled="false"
                     md-no-cache="true"
                     md-selected-item="selectedItem"
                     md-search-text-change="searchTextChange(searchText)"
                     md-search-text="searchText"
                     md-selected-item-change="selectedItemChange(item)"
                     md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)"
                     md-item-text="item.name"
                     md-min-length="0"
                     placeholder="search"
                     md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template">
        <md-item-template>
            <span class="item-title" ng-click="navigate();searchText=''">
                <img ng-if="item.type=='USER'" ng-src="{{item.url}}" height="20" width="20" class="img-circle"/>
                <span> {{item.name}} </span>
            </span>
        </md-item-template>
    </md-autocomplete>
</form>
```

Comment: whats the problem, current vs expected?

Comment: @alphapilgrim after scrolling my dashboard,when user wants to search and enters names,it is unable display the names .